# Read Core data in Serial Queue for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have an app which uses Core data and the values are fetched from a link on internet.

This runs absolutely fine when I am creating a serial queue in AppDelegate and I am not facing any problem with the same.

Now, when I am trying to re-create similar scenario in a UITableViewController and executing the same in a serial queue but when the control reaches

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *match = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

execution control disappears and then this code remains in the execution till eternity.

Can anyone help me with what exactly is wrong here?

FYI, I am passing the same ManagedObjectContext to the serial queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last sentence may be the key: managed object contexts are *not* designed to be used by more than one thread/queue. See the [concurrency section in the Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) for more on that. If your app only needs to support iOS 5+, then you may be able to solve this (and get out of managing your own serial queue) with the [new private queue context](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) added in 5.0. Otherwise, you *must* ensure that each thread/queue has its own context, and that you only pass safe information (like managed object IDs) from one context to another.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did used the same Context but did the pre-fetching and processing in the different block and then re-saved the data in main block. I did try to use this private queue thing but unfortunately failed to achieve it.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Core Data on iOS video from WWDC 2011 has a pretty good intro to those: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/includes/whats-new-in-core-data-on-ios.html#whats-new-in-core-data-on-ios

Comment: @Otto: Thanks for the reference. This was pretty helpful. Also, I used the NSOperation and NSOperationQueue which also operates in the Asynchronous mode.